# Flutter & Firebase Dynamic Links

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

I would like to use Firebase Dynamic Links to open the email verification message in the app by tapping the link sent by email.

In the Dynamic Link created, the package name of the app is given so that the app can start when the link is tapped.

My question is : do I need my app to be in the PlayStore so that the app can be recognized and opened, or can I test the dynamic link app opening even if my app hasn't been published.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test dynamic links without having the app published in the stores. It just has to be installed on the device of course.